# JQuery Toggle...one click to open - double to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, toggle

I created a mobile menu with a toggle switch.

When I click on the div "dropdown-menu" it opens.
When I click again it closes. But i want it to open with one click and to close with double click.

What do I need to add to my code??

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");}
);

$('.dropdown-menu').blur(function() {
    $('.dropdown-inside').hide('slow', function() {
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [dblclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick),

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
   $('.dropdown-menu').children('ul').slideUp("slow");// slideUp all drop-downs
   $(this).children('ul').slideDown("slow");// use slideDown instead slideToggle
});

$('.dropdown-menu').dblclick(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
});
```

To prevent `sliding` after `clicking once` try this,

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
   if( !$(this).children('ul').is(':visible')) {// slide, if ul is not visible
       $('.dropdown-menu').children('ul').slideUp("slow");
       $(this).children('ul').slideDown("slow");
   }
});
```